# How to prove that the following is a martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $X_0 = 0$ and for $i \geq 0$, let $X_{i+1}$ be chosen uniformly over the interval $[X_i, 1]$. prove that $M_n = 2^n (1-X_n)$ for $n \geq 0$ is a martingale, and prove that $M_n$ converges to a finite valued limit.

I am confused about how to even prove that $M_n$ is a martingale, because isn't $E|M_n| = 2^n E|1-X_n|  \rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Edit: Say I want to use the martingale convergence theorem to prove that $M_n$ converges to a finite valued limit. How can I show that $\sup_n E|M_n| < \infty$, when $E|M_n| < 2^n$? Does the supremum not exist?

Comment: Clearly $\mathbb E[X_1] = \frac12$. By induction you can show that $\mathbb E[X_n] = 1-2^{-n}$ and hence $\mathbb E[1-X_n]=2^{-n}$. So $\mathbb E[|M_n|] = 2^n\cdot 2^{-n}=1$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

hint:

$$E(M_{n+1}|X_1,\cdots ,X_n)=E(2^{n+1} (1-X_{n+1})|X_1,\cdots ,X_n)$$

$$=E(2^{n+1} (1-X_{n+1})|X_1,\cdots ,X_n)=2^{n+1} (1-E(X_{n+1}|X_1,\cdots ,X_n))$$

$$=2^{n+1} (1-\frac{X_n+1}{2})=M_n$$

Since this martingale is positive so it converge, non-negative martingale converge  [Corollary 2.3.](http://math.tkk.fi/teaching/stokanal/lecture3.pdf),or [Corollary 5.3.5.](http://web.math.ku.dk/noter/filer/vidsand12.pdf) you do not need go for checking uniformly intgrablity .

Comment: thanks. I got that part of it already, but isn't there also a requirement for martingales that $E|M_n| < \infty$? Is this something I should be proving using L'hopital's rule e.g. assuming that $E|1-X_n| \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: I think $E|M_n|<2^n$

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I'm confused because if you take $n\rightarrow\infty$ doesn't that mean that $E|M_n| < \infty$ fails? or does that condition hold for a fixed n?

Comment: I think it should hold for every fixed  $n$.

Comment: page 2 https://www.math.wisc.edu/~roch/teaching_files/275b.1.12w/lect3-web.pdf